# Visual Studio lower icon pixels

Tags: visual-studio, icons, pixel

So this is how it started... I've managed to create an icon for my program in Visual Studio. The icon looked perfectly smooth in photoshop. I saved the file as .ico with using a photoshop plugin. I want the transparency so my icon was saved as 8 bit RGB. After importing the icon in my exe then [this happened.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GFU8.png)

Answer (score 0):

(Posted on behalf of the OP).

I've downloaded IcoFX and opened my file as 8 bit RGB png. Then I clicked: Image(from the top navigation menu) -> Create Windows Icon From Image. It detected it as Windows Vista because it's resolution is 256x256. Finally saved it and imported it in my Visual Studio project. The icon was so smooth after following this procedure!